# How do I hard-code arguments in emacs lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I have the following function in my `.emacs` that notifies me after I've worked for a suitable amount of time.

Problem is, I'm unable to hardcode the values time and msg, so I have to reenter them each time.

```
(defun timed-notification(time msg)
  (interactive "sNotification when (e.g: 2 minutes, 60 seconds, 3 days): \nsMessage: ")
  (run-at-time time
               nil
               (lambda (msg) (terminal-notifier-notify "Pomodoro" msg))
               msg))
(setq column-number-mode t)
```

How do I set the time to always be "25 min" and the message to be "Take a break, time's up!"?

Here is my attempt:

```
(defun timed-notification()
  ;(interactive "sNotification when (e.g: 2 minutes, 60 seconds, 3 days): \nsMessage: ")
  (run-at-time 25
               nil
               (lambda ("Time's up")
                 (terminal-notifier-notify "Take a break, time's up!" msg))
               msg))
(setq column-number-mode t)
```

Comment: Perhaps also note http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TypeBreakMode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got rid of the `msg` parameter, but you were still trying to use it. Use `let` to bind a local variable to that value.

```
(defun timed-notification()
  (interactive)
  (let ((msg "Take a break, time's up!"))
    (run-at-time 25 nil (lambda (mess) (terminal-notifier-notify "pomodoro" mess)) msg)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this works, but now I'm unable to start the timed-notification with M-x. Adding a bogus line like (interactive "sadfasdf") makes timed-notification findable with M-x again, but it wont run ("Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive "sadfa...""). Complete newb here, so the solution is probably simple.

Comment: If the function takes no arguments, it should just be `(interactive)`.

Comment: Each line in the argument string to `interactive` is the prompt for an argument.

Comment: Thanks, realized that myself too.

Comment: I didn't even notice that when I was copying his code. I've fixed it. I've used different variable names for the variable in the lambda and the one in the function, to make the distinction clear.

Answer (score 2):

Define your function like you did originally, then invoke it once with the parameters you want.  The `interactive` form, like its name suggests, is only used when you actually invoke the function interactively.  When you invoke it from code, you pass the parameters; so the `interactive` form is simply ignored.

```
(defun timed-notification (time msg)
  (interactive "sNotification when (e.g: 2 minutes, 60 seconds, 3 days): \nsMessage: ")
  (run-at-time time nil (lambda (msg) (terminal-notifier-notify "Pomodoro" msg)) msg))
(setq column-number-mode t)
(timed-notification 25 "Take a break, time's up!")  ;; New addition
```

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I could make a new (interactive) function that calls (timed-notifications 25 "times up!") and call it something else. That way I won't have to destroy the original function.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun timed-notification (time msg)
  (interactive "sNotification when (e.g: 2 minutes, 60 seconds, 3 days): \nsMessage: ")
  (run-at-time time nil (lambda (msg) (terminal-notifier-notify "Pomodoro" msg)) msg))
(setq column-number-mode t)

(defun tf()
  (interactive)
  (timed-notification "1 min" "Take a break, time's up!"))
```

Now tf can be called for a regular pomo, while the original function is still available for when I want an x-minute break.